# Netsuite - How do I import custom item number fields of a serialized item into Netsuite along with their corresponding serial numbers?

Tags: netsuite

I have couple of serialized items setup on my account. I have some custom item number fields also setup to define the individual serial numbered item records(Device ID, IMEI etc.). Now I have 2000 serialized numbers along with the values for device id, IMEI in a csv for importing into NS.
How do I import this 2000 serialized numbers for an item?
How do I import Custom item number field values also along with these serial numbers?

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing items, you can add a field called 'serialnumbers' and map that to the serial number field on the CSV Import Wizard mapping field.

The values in the 'serialnumbers' field will be the serial nos of the item with each number separated by a comma.

Do note that if you are also importing quantity on hand for the item, the number of serial numbers should be equal to the quantity on hand.  Can't recall if you can import serial numbers for items with zero quantity on hand.

As for the custom item number fields, as far as I know these are not accessible via the CSV Import Wizard.  You will need to use SuiteScript to set values for those during import.

Comment: Thanks for the info, how to use suitescript to set values for item number fields during import? I am new to suitescript.